# Material to re-stucco compromised exterior wall

Tags: exterior, stucco, refinishing

The extension to my house was built (I estimate in the 1930s) using terracota hollow blocks with stucco over. For some decades, the stucco had vinyl siding over it, which was an awful choice because it couldn't be properly attached to the hollow underlayment (fasteners didn't bite into the hollow blocks), so it was detaching and I ripped it off. That exposed the stucco under, which was old, cracked, and ugly. I did some repairs, which can be seen, to improve waterproofing, which didn't make it any prettier.

[image]
[image]

Now, I would like to restucco and make it all look nice and smooth. But I am not sure which material to use. I have used regular mortar/stucco from the Home Depot, the same thing for laying bricks, to stucco a brick wall and thought it was hard to make the final coat smooth. Are there other, more specialized products that can be smeared or maybe even applied with a roller that would provide a thin final coat of stucco over this old, rought surface that I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

you will only temporary cover those cracks, they will aper again.

Use stucco products in a tube and press them in.

Your skill set for plastering needs some improvement, practice.

Stucco comes generally in two versions.

Use the one called for Top coat.

Comment: would [this](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCGoGMhiegfG__FMNSdLlZM4VMjcli4pK-UDg23UN_dM-OZTHW0S0OiorOR4bZtxoFG1AV5BSQ5X_WxsytVjblZaxLM3O1ew) be a top coat?

Comment: @amphibient yes, it is a finish coat.

Comment: you think i could just skim that over, sort of like a last coat of drywall mud?

Comment: @amphibient you could if you use the right trowel for the job. You are using way to narrow trowel, that is why you get your results. You are trying to smear some stucco over the cracks. That will not work,  the cracks will reaper in short time. You have to fill them first with tube stucco made for that purpose, also moist the work area for better adhesion

Comment: 12-in x 4-in Rubber Stucco Float

Comment: possible. i was using a metal trowel of those same dimenstions

Comment: metal trowel are good for flat surface, you stucco is not flat, rubber is better.

Comment: well that makes sense

Comment: If it does, go ahead accept my answer so we can call it closed.